Comedy with no cookies
I remember an early scene of a movie which I've seen several years ago - at least 5 years ago, probably more - while it was aired in Italy (with dubbing, as it is customary here). As you'll see from the description, it looked like comedy and it was probably set in the second half of the 20th century.
Unfortunately, that scene is the only one I've ever seen from that movie. I'm going to trust my memory and write all the few details I remember.
The movie I'm looking for starts with some scenes of the youth of the narrator - an Afro American male from a stereotyped low wealth Afro American family.
He says something like: «we were so poor we didn't have cookies...» - the camera looks down at the boy as he reaches up into a kitchen cabinet, taking out a frisbee-sized, tin-colored plastic envelope with a lonely, big, black "cookie" word printed on it - «...we had "cookie".»
The boy the asks mom if he can have some. It's a giant chocolat chips cookie.

Sounds like the Everybody Hates Chris episode Everybody Hates Food Stamps from 2005 (Season 1, Episode 9), though it's not a movie, and it's a girl in that scene. The show is about a boy growing up in a working class African-American family in the 80s, and in that episode:

Julius finds food stamps and urges his wife to use them. Being a "ghetto snob", Rochelle is naturally nervous to seen using food stamps though she is happy that for once they'll be able to buy brand name food.

One of those generic food items they bought before that was the one you described. The narrator (Chris Rock) says they didn't have cookies but rather just 'cookie'; cut to his sister as she reaches into the cabinet and asks her mother if she can have 'cookie', which is a huge pizza-shaped cookie in a plastic wrapper. You can see the scene here around 0:46.

My university refectory had ice creams called "cone", "biscuit" and "coated", with similar plastic wrappers. No wonder I felt sympathetic with poor Chris and family.
